# How to project ECW with FME?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I would like to project ECW + MITAB with FME to Geodatabase.

For example, i have the header MiTab:

> !table !version 300 !charset WindowsLatin1   Definition Table   File
>   "7007_0652_0656_A08.ecw"   Type "RASTER" (381028.028, 5255481.97)
>   (0,0) Label "NWCor", (381028.028, 5253732.95) (0,11660) Label "SWCor",
>   (382131.9, 5253732.95) (7359,11660) Label "SECor", (382131.9,
>   5255481.97) (7359,0) Label "NECor" CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 33, "m", -69, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0 Bounds (-7745844.29605, -9997964.94315)
>   (8745844.29605, 9997964.94315)  Units "m"

How to project the ecw raster to Geodatabase ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the MapInfo TAB file (is this the same as MITAB?) is in the same folder as the raster, and with the same name, then FME should automatically pick up the correct coordinate system. You can try reading the data into the FME Universal Viewer (and then query a feature) to confirm this.

To control the resampling process you'll need to use a Reprojector transformer, as the Navigator window doesn't have the resampling parameters in there. I believe it would just default to nearest neighbor. But if that's OK just use the Navigator window options.

Answer (score 0):

ECW to Tiff [Reproject] to Geodatabase Raster

"Reprojecting
Reprojecting is the operation of transforming a feature from one coordinate system to another.
Raster reprojection works in the same way, but involves a resampling process to accommodate
the change in size and shape of the raster cells.
**FME has 5 re-sampling methods: Nearest Neighbour, Bicubic, Bilinear, Average4 and Average16.**
The method to choose is dependent on the source dataset and performance requirements. While
Bicubic or Bilinear resampling produces a much better visual output, Nearest Neighbour gives the
best performance. Average4 and 16 re-sampling is mostly used in Digital Elevation Models."

http://www.fmeuc.com/archive/2009downloads/workshops/FMEUC09-RasterWorkshop.pdf
(page 20)

Comment: Does the pratical scenario use MITAB for the projection ?